# Search all function cannot work when not selecting 'utf8' encoding

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Here is my setting.json:

```
{   
  "files.autoGuessEncoding": true,
  "files.encoding": "cp950"
}
```

That's weird that the setting above cannot get any result from searching all. (ctrl + alt + F)

After I change the setting to be

```
{   
      "files.autoGuessEncoding": true,
      "files.encoding": "utf8"
}
```

then it works well.

I have tested in both Mac OS and Windows. The situation are same.
No matter the encoding of document, since I tried several encoding types , including cp950, big5 ... and so on. Searching all function only works on utf8.

Does anyone encounter this problem? and how to fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `"utf8"`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason. 
The search tool in VS code doesn't support auto detection of encodings.
Please  set **"files.autoGuessEncoding": false**, the problem maybe resolved.